# If the dependent variable has both positive and negative values, how to approach any machine learning algorithm?

Tags: python, regression, artificial-intelligence

If the dependent variable has both positive and negative values, the model.score of any regression models are not accurate when train and test score are compared. I tried converting the target column into log but since there are negative values as well, it seems this is not right. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any machine learning algorithms that can't handle both positive and negative values. The scoring should still be accurate. If you would like to take the log transform of a column with negative values, then you can add some large constant to the column that makes all values positive and then take the log.